# Ubuntu 16.04 dual-boot install failure

Tags: system-installation, windows, acpi

I have been trying to install Ubuntu 16.04 alongside Windows 10 
but after creating a LiveUSB drive and booting with it, an error occurs which is related to some ACPI ...something

```
[ 0.000000] ACPI Error: [GPLD] Namespace lookup failure, AE_ALREADY_EXISTS (20170831/dulload-378)   
[ 0.000000] ACPI Exception: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, During name lookup/catalog (20170831/psobject-252)  
[ 0.000000] ACPI Exception: AE_ALREADY_EXISTS, (SSDT:84DA   ) while loading table (20170831/tbxfload-228)   
[ 0.000000] ACPI Error: 1 table load failures, 13 successful (20170831/tbxfload-246)  
[ 0.056840] ACPI Exception: AE_BAD_PARAMETER, Could not install PciConfig handler for Root Bridge PCIO (20170831/evrgnini-245)   
[ 4.597806] tpm tpm0: A TPM error (378) occurred get tpm pcr allocation   
[ 4.679211] Couldn't get size: Ox000000000000000e   
[ 7.300165] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found   
[ 7.300183] sd 5:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
```

The image of the error is [attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GPZLW.jpg). and after Ubuntu installation starts, the installer freezes; I have to manually switch off the laptop.  How may I proceed towards a resolution of the boot failure with ACPI error mesages?

Comment: 1)Text of error messages is infinitely preferable to images; see your edited question for an example. 2) Have you turned off Fast Boot and Secure Boot in this laptop? 3) What is the make and model of the laptop; please get the model number from the serial number sticker, as model names on the lid, bezels, and surrounds are generally not useful. 4) Please provide 2) and 3) by clicking on [edit] and adding that to your question; please do not use Add Comment, but instead use [edit].